# Executing method after screen load

Tags: acumatica

I have had a few items come up recently where I have a need to execute a method immediately after initial screen load.

For example a couple scenario's:

1) Processing screen where the data shown in the processing screen comes from an external API (dynamically loaded and parsed, then displayed for processing)

2) Automatically load a second window/tab when the screen finishes loading based on data in the record.

3) A popup prompt after screen load notifying the user of a situation on the item the loaded.

All three of these present different challenges which lead me to wonder if what the best day to handle these would be.

For example, item 1 - currently I have an a call in the "GetRecords" override that if the View contains no records, calls the a long running process to go grab the records.   While this works, I'm presented with two issues

- If I let the long process run and then request a refresh, the user has the ability to click "Process/Process All" before data is available.    This also effects scheduling of the process.
- If I block the process with a WaitTillCompleted, the user is presented with a standard page loading spinner instead of the "Long running Process" indicator but allows scheduling to work correctly.

For #2/3,  the request for the new window/tab and the popup both seem to be initiated from a postback to function correctly.   That leads me to believe I need a javascript method to run after the page finishes init to execute the appropriate actions.

Is there a better way to handle either of these situations with native framework methods?

Comment: Do you need to do it on a custom page or the existing page?

Comment: Both actually.   scenario #1 / #3 are custom.   #2 / #3 are customized stock

Comment: In case of customized stock you can override Initialize method. It's being called when base graph is done

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly answer the need to call a method in page load, here are some options for checking for running process to control buttons or displaying messages outside of a popup...

We have some areas where we want to wait or prevent users from re-processing before the last process completes and have implemented some of the following examples.

Check to see if the process is currently running. Could be used to disable buttons or exist action buttons...

```
PXLongOperation.GetStatus(this.UID) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess
```

Wait for the currently running process to finish...

```
PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(this.UID);
```

I have not worked with a popup during data load but you might be better off presenting a row warning/error for the displayed data rather than a pop up?

```
CyclesList.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<ARStatementCycle.statementCycleId>(
    row, row.StatementCycleId,
    new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.WRN_ProcessStatementDetectsOverdueInvoicesAndUnappliedPayments, PXErrorLevel.RowWarning));
```